# Python divide cell by sum of group

Tags: python, pandas

New to python and just hoping to get some help

I have a data frame that is players, team and number of shots in a game. I want to create a column that is the proportion of a team's shots a player takes
So my data frame looks something like this

| Player | Team | Shots |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PlayA | A | 4 |
| PlayB | A | 6 |
| PlayC | B | 5 |
| PlayD | B | 15 |

and what I want is

| Player | Team | Shots | Shot Prop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PlayA | A | 4 | 0.4 |
| PlayB | A | 6 | 0.6 |
| PlayC | B | 5 | 0.25 |
| PlayD | B | 15 | 0.75 |

But in reality there is no set number of players or teams

Any help is very appreciated

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: `df['Short Prop'] = df['Short'] / df.groupby('Team')['Short'].transform('sum')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and `sum` for repeat aggregate values to Series wit same size like original:

```
df['Short Prop'] = df['Short'].div(df.groupby('Team')['Short'].transform('sum'))
```